# How to open an external URL in Ionic 2 InAppBrowser?

Tags: android, ionic2, inappbrowser

I use the following Ionic 2 Dropbox code: [ionic2-dropbox](https://github.com/alexandrzavalii/ionic2-dropbox) and I've also tried this tutorial: [Integrating Ionic 2 with the Dropbox API](http://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-ionic-2-with-the-dropbox-api-part-2/) both are opening an external browser instead of an actual in-app-browser (_blank) as described here [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). I tried with Nexus 5 and Samsung S4 mini. Both devices open an external browser. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried that: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/launch-websites-with-ionic-2-using-the-inappbrowser/?

Comment: Give me a second, I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open the page in the internal in-app-browser you need to use the parameter _self instead of _blank.

Hope that helps!